# Updating the new String in the layout screen not randomly, but in a pattern(i.e. like 0,1,2,3,4..) whenever the button is clicked

Tags: android, arrays, xml, string, android-layout

So, I want to update my screen with new string not generated randomly but it should update the string in order(like ascending order) whenever the button is clicked. I want to remove the random function and used a code which can help me update the string in order. And when I reached my maximum index String array, it should return to index 0.

//Additional question
How can I go back to my previous String using the back button without using any new activities? Now I want the option to return back in descending order.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
 private TextView funFactTextView;
    private Button buttonFact;
    private Button backButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        funFactTextView = findViewById(R.id.funFactTextView);
        buttonFact = findViewById(R.id.buttonFact);
        backButton = findViewById(R.id.backButton);

       View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String[] facts = {
                                "Ants stretch when they wake up in the morning.",
                                "Ostriches can run faster than horses.",
                                "Olympic gold medals are actually made mostly of silver.",
                                "You are born with 300 bones; by the time you are an adult you will have 206.",
                                "It takes about 8 minutes for light from the Sun to reach Earth.",
                                "Some bamboo plants can grow almost a meter in just one day.",
                                "The state of Florida is bigger than England.",
                                "Some penguins can leap 2-3 meters out of the water.",
                                "On average, it takes 66 days to form a new habit.",
                                "Mammoths still walked the earth when the Great Pyramid was being built." };
                        Random random = new Random();
                        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(facts.length);
                        String fact = facts[randomNumber];
                        funFactTextView.setText(fact);//set the new string 
                    }
                };
                buttonFact.setOnClickListener(listener);//button clicked updates new string
```

Comment: what is your aim or what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to display the array of Strings in an ordered manner whenever the button is clicked. At the moment the code generates a random string, but I want to generate the String in a pattern (like when I click the button, it should display 1st String, 2nd String, 3rd String, 4th String...and so on)

Answer (score 2):

You can write the function as below

Decalre gloabal variable outside the method

```
 private int i=0;



View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String[] facts = {
                            "Ants stretch when they wake up in the morning.",
                            "Ostriches can run faster than horses.",
                            "Olympic gold medals are actually made mostly of silver.",
                            "You are born with 300 bones; by the time you are an adult you will have 206.",
                            "It takes about 8 minutes for light from the Sun to reach Earth.",
                            "Some bamboo plants can grow almost a meter in just one day.",
                            "The state of Florida is bigger than England.",
                            "Some penguins can leap 2-3 meters out of the water.",
                            "On average, it takes 66 days to form a new habit.",
                            "Mammoths still walked the earth when the Great Pyramid was being built." };
                    if(i==facts.length)
                    {
                     i=0;
                    }
                    String fact = facts[i];
                    funFactTextView.setText(fact);//set the new string 
                    i++;
                }
            };
            buttonFact.setOnClickListener(listener);//button clicked updates new string
```

Comment: final int[] i = {0};    if(i[0] ==facts.length)
                {
                    i[0] =0;
                }
                String fact = facts[i[0]];
                funFactTextView.setText(fact);//set the new string
                i[0]++;  We need to edit it this. Then it works fine.

Comment: I have some more additional questions now that this question is answered.

Comment: Sure. You can raise a new question

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with my code and it will work:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String[] facts = {
                    "Ants stretch when they wake up in the morning.",
                    "Ostriches can run faster than horses.",
                    "Olympic gold medals are actually made mostly of silver.",
                    "You are born with 300 bones; by the time you are an adult you will have 206.",
                    "It takes about 8 minutes for light from the Sun to reach Earth.",
                    "Some bamboo plants can grow almost a meter in just one day.",
                    "The state of Florida is bigger than England.",
                    "Some penguins can leap 2-3 meters out of the water.",
                    "On average, it takes 66 days to form a new habit.",
                    "Mammoths still walked the earth when the Great Pyramid was being built." };
            String fact = "";
            for(int i=0;i<facts.length;i++)
            {
                fact+=facts[i];
            }

            funFactTextView.setText(fact);//set the new string 
        }
    };
    buttonFact.setOnClickListener(listener);//button clicked updates new string
```

Comment: While posting answer you should also describe what changes you recommend to do or what's wrong with the asker's code.

Comment: @VivekMishra I'll take care of it in future. Thanks

Comment: It displays the whole 10 strings available. The strings concatenate each other and display the whole string.

Comment: use @VirRajput's answer. now I know what you want. He already explained it.

Comment: I have some more additional questions now that this question is answered.

Comment: can you update your code with recent?
then I can update your code.